# Align paragraph in paracol at the top by force

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, alignment, paracol

Paracol is a package that allows for synchronized multi-column typesetting. However, I find a situation where paragraphs in two columns not aligned at the top. Here's the MWE that just shows the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}
\author{kraanium13 }
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{paracol}{2}
test \footnote{a regular footnote}
test \footnote{a regular footnote}
\switchcolumn
no footnote text
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

and this produces the following document that seems weired
[image]

this happens because the left column does not have enough space to put the footnote, so that the content is flushed to the next page. However, the right column remains unaffected. This results in a situation where the first line of the left column is on a different page than that of the right column.

However, I wish to make them aligned at the top (i.e. the first line of the left and the right column should at least stand on the same page). There are some possible solutions that I can think of:

1. To add a vertical space to the right column to make them flush to a new page. The amount should be the same as what TeX adds to the left column.
2. More generally, can we determine whether a page break should be triggered before putting any text?
3. To force keeping the line with footnote mark on the previous page, but the footnote text on the next page. This will cause some discrepancy but I have seen this behavior when the footnote is long.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't enough room for the footnote text on the same page as the footnote marks, so the marks are deliberately delayed to the next page.

Comment: It is correct identification of the problem. But is it possible to solve it? Are we able to know that TeX triggers a page break before putting any real content? If so, we can automatically apply a \newpage before paracol env.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't see what your point is: perhaps incorrect use of package `paracol`?

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
%\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}
\author{kraanium13 }
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[5-6]\bigskip

\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn[0]
  test \footnote{a regular footnote}
  test \footnote{a regular footnote}
\switchcolumn[1]
 no footnote text\bigskip
 
 but here's a footnote\footnote{right column}
 
\switchcolumn[0]
 \lipsum[5]
 
\switchcolumn[1]
 \lipsum[5]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response! The problem happens when the remaining page cannot hold the footnote, so that the left part of the text is flushed to the next page to keep footnote mark and footnote text together. However, the right column does have enough space to put the line "no footnote text", so it does not trigger a page break. As a result, the first line of the left column is on a different page than that of the right column, however, I wish to make them aligned.

Comment: The problem is updated with better explanation and some desired solutions I want to achieve.

Comment: Please try using the \switchcolumn[x] as I showed. Your currently posted code does something else. Does this change your problem, perhaps even solve it?

Comment: Well, I believe using \switchcolumn[x] does not make any difference. The real problem is with how TeX treats pagebreak. Please see a even simpler MWE where I use \vspace to limit vertical space on the first page. \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\vspace*{10em}
\begin{paracol}{2}
left column paragraph with footnote\footnote{lorem} will be flushed to the next page
\switchcolumn[1]
right column paragraph will remain on first page
\end{paracol}
\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to force the footnote marks to be on a different page than the footnote text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\title{Paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}
\author{kraanium13 }
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{20\baselineskip}

\begin{paracol}{2}
test \footnotemark \edef\tempnumber{\thefootnote}
test \footnotemark
\newpage
\footnotetext[\tempnumber]{a regular footnote}
\footnotetext{a regular footnote}
\switchcolumn
no footnote text
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response. I think it is a good workaround. But in this case, I would rather add a manual \newpage before the paracol environment, so that both columns would start at the next page and would solve my problem. I am wondering if a somehow automatic solution is possible since I am using paracol a lot in my long book.

Comment: See the needspace package.